# Telegram Bot Удалить сообщение бота

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

Использую pyTelegramBotAPI
Как удалять сообщения бота в чате? Например: бот выдает пользователю несколько кнопок, а при нажатии на одну из них поле с кнопками удаляется.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id)
```

P.S:

- Сообщение можно удалить только в том случае, если оно было отправлено
  менее *48* часов назад.
- Боты могут удалять исходящие сообщения в группах и супергруппах.
- Боты, которым предоставлены права `can_post_messages`, могут удалять
  исходящие сообщения в каналах.
- Если бот является администратором группы, он может удалить там любое
  сообщение.
- Если бот имеет разрешение `can_delete_messages` в супергруппе или
  канале, он может удалить там любое сообщение. Возвращает `True` в
  случае успеха.

---

[Документация](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#deletemessage)

Answer (score 0):

Тут скорее всего надо не удалять, а редактировать.
Подробнее описано тут:
https://github.com/TelegramBot/Api/issues/196#issuecomment-509209933

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).